# eclipse android error: Duplicate file

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I don't have any error on my android project but when i run my my project on eclipse i get this error, but i don't know how i can fix it, please any one can help me to solve this error! And Thanks in advance

Error screenshot:
[image]

> C:\Users\asus\FinderPhone\FinderPhone\res\values-w820dp-v13\dimens.xml:
>   error: Duplicate file.
>   C:\Users\asus\FinderPhone\FinderPhone\res\values-w820dp\dimens.xml:
>   Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.

Comment: delete values-w820dp-v13 folder and try to run

Comment: what is the minimum version you set for the project? if it is after or at api 13 then eclipse probably realised that both xml files will be used, that's why you get the error, because it can't pick between the two

Comment: blkrt: I deleted the folder values-w820dp-v-13 but i get many other errors on my project!!! :(

Cruces: the minimum version is 11, but i tryed with many other version it still same error :(

Comment: Anyway (blkrt & Cruces ) thanks for your helps

Comment: @A.ZAKI  `clean` the project and `rebuild` it .

Comment: @Ironman it's done but i get the same error :(